# Split string when encountered two regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex expression to split a String when encouter a 
 tag, or a emoji colon sintaxe.

Example: 
`"hello here comes emoji :grinning: and a line break <br> one more emoji :heart:"`

What i wanna acomplish is an array like:

```
[
 "hello here comes emoji",
 ":grinning:",
 "and a line break",
 "<br>",
 "one more emoji",
 ":heart:"
]
```

I have the regex that separately do that:

Split on emojis `split(/(:[^\s:]+(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?:)/)`

Split on br `split(/(<br>)/g)`

What I want is a way to join the both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join the patterns with a `|` alternation operator:

```
/\s*(:[^\s:]+(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?:|<br>)\s*/
```

Note I added `\s*` on both sides to trim whitespace.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "hello here comes emoji :grinning: and a line break <br> one more emoji :heart:";
var reg = /\s*(:[^\s:]+(?:::skin-tone-[2-6])?:|<br>)\s*/;
console.log(s.split(reg).filter(x => x.trim().length !=0 ));
```